# Updating heroku config variables for a react app in code

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables, react-scripts

I am working on a React app that needs to update its Heroku config vars in code. I'm able to successfully update the vars using the Heroku Platform API and can see these changes reflected in on my heroku app dashboard. The app restarts when I update the config vars, but when I check the values of `process.env` in the app after the restart, they are not updated.

Update code:

```
const config = {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3",
                Authorization: `Bearer <Token>`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }
        }
const configVars = {
            "REACT_APP_VAR": var
        }
axios.patch('https://api.heroku.com/apps/<app name>/config-vars', configVars, config)
            .then(res => { 
                console.log(res);
            })
```

I can also `GET` these variables within the same app and see the changes reflected.

```
const config = {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3",
                Authorization: `Bearer <Token>`
              }
        }
        axios.get(`https://api.heroku.com/apps/<app name>/config-vars`, config)
            .then(res => {
                const configVars = res.data;
                console.log("Received config vars: ", configVars);
                setLoading(false);
            })
```

I am using the `REACT_APP_` notation on all environmental variables since we're using `react-scripts` and am not deploying my `.env` file to the production site, it's pulling the variables from heroku itself.

I am using `process.env.REACT_APP_<VAR NAME>` to actually reference/use these variables in code. I feel like I approaching this problem incorrectly and am fighting the core `env` functionality in Heroku and `react-scripts`, but I am hoping someone knows how to get the `process.env` vars to update.

Comment: In any case, this will never work. React runs _client-side_, not server-side. It has no access to environment variables on the server. Instead, certain environment variables prefixed by `REACT_APP_` get compiled into your application at build time. To pick up new environment variables in React you must rebuild your application.

Comment: "I feel like I approaching this problem incorrectly"—this is a good instinct. You are facing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627), where "change environment variables at runtime" is the solution you think you need to solve problem X, so you are asking abut changing environment variables at runtime instead of asking about X. What is X here? Why do you think you need to change environment variables at runtime? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I spent more time digging into this problem and came to the same conclusion as I've learned more about how react injects env vars during the build. The "X" in this case was a dynamic URL to be shared across all users to determine our backend endpoint. We wanted the ability to change this value within the app itself to point to a different backend. This is for a school project with an approaching deadline, so I went with a hacky solution and have another, static api endpoint that I use to get/set these values instead. Not an ideal solution, but for my use case it worked.